# How can I exclude rows from my df where in column A, and column B the first 4 decimals are equal?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I exclude rows from my df where in column A, and column B the first 4 decimals are equal?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {A: [6.03459, 4.08876],'B': [6.03451, 4.13796],'C': ['five', 'one']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

I was trying something like this df[~pd.np.isclose(df.legs[0][:4], df.wings[0][:4]]

In this case it will exclude first row 6.0345 = 6.0345

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line:

```
df = df.loc[~(np.floor(df['A']*10000)==np.floor(df['B']*10000))]
```

Since you are looking for comparing the decimals then rounding wouldn't help. Floor converts to integers so it removes all decimal points but if you multiply by 10000 and then take the floor then you are actually comparing the first 4 decimals which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use pandas `diff` and `abs` and check greater than or equal 1 by `ge(1)` to create the mask `m`. Finally, use this mask to slice your `df`

```
m = (df[['A', 'B']] * 10000).diff(axis=1)['B'].abs().ge(1)
df[m]

Out[266]:
         A        B    C
1  4.08876  4.13796  one
```